where do i find the package for xsane in Ubuntu 24.04
I want to install the xsane scanner package on Ubuntu 24.04
The ubuntu manual says that it is available in ubuntu 24.04
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/xsane.1.html
but I cannot find it in the App Centre. If i search the App Centre for xsane it offers me Image Scan which does not work with my scanner.

Have you enabled the "universe" repository? See for example How do I enable the "Universe" repository?

xsane | 0.999-12ubuntu4  | noble/universe         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x

Many packages in universe or the community package source (many from upstream Debian) will only be found in package managers (not app stores), but can be installed via terminal.

run this command from terminal to install sudo apt install xsane
